# how to hide id from the url and make it clean url my directory of .htaccess file is /home/evidhya/public_html/tutorials/.htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have following  url i would like to hide id and make it clean url

`https://www.evidhya.com/tutorials/tutorials.php?qid=569/AJAX/Introduction`

clean url should be like below url
`https://www.evidhya.com/tutorials/AJAX/Introduction`

I'm able to achieve using below htaccess code.
`https://www.evidhya.com/tutorials/569/AJAX/Introduction`
but i don't want `569` id in url

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /KSTA-Webinar/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
#RewriteRule ^(\d+)/?$ tutorials.php?qid=$1/$2/$1/$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([\w.-]+)/?$ get_data.php?qid=$1 [L,QSA]
          
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^title=([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.+)$
RewriteRule ^tutorials\.php$ /%1/%2/%4? [R=301]

RewriteRule ^tutorials/([\w+%]{2,50})$ /tutorials.php?qid=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ tutorials.php?qid=$1&user=$2&date=$3

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.+)$ tutorials.php?qid=$1/$2/$1/$3 [L]
```

Comment: Hard to tell what your actual question is here. But you are aware that in some place you will still have to perform the “translation” from `ADO/Introduction` back to the id `459`, right? If you don’t want to hard-code that into the .htaccess for every single case, then your script logic behind this will likely need modification as well.

Comment: `/tutorials/ADO/Introduction` cannot be rewritten to `/tutorials/tutorials.php?qid=459` because `459` is not present anywhere in original URI. You can rewrite ``/tutorials/ADO/Introduction`` to something like `/tutorials/get_data.php?param1=ADO&param2=Introduction` and then let `get_data.php` fetch right content from database.

Comment: @JaiPrakash: Any response on my comment above. Do mention my name as @ anubhava when you leave a comment here

Comment: sorry question is still unclear

Comment: `i don't want 569 id in url`: But why do you want to hide `569`?

Comment: sir actually https://www.evidhya.com/tutorials/569/AJAX/Introduction this is not looking like clean url if we will remove 569 id it will be looks like clean url  https://www.evidhya.com/tutorials/AJAX/Introduction

Comment: Having an id in URL doesn't make it bad for any purpose.  Just see URL of this question `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60225143/how-to-hide-id-from-the-url-and-make-it-clean-url-my-directory-of-htaccess-file` where we have id and title

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems the id is needed to determine the resulting url.
I would do this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (\d+)/(\w+)/(\w+) tutorials.php?qid=$1/$2/$3 [L]
```

and place this rule in `tutorials/.htaccess`.

And when someone goes to https://www.evidhya.com/tutorials/569/AJAX/Introduction it should load https://www.evidhya.com/tutorials/tutorials.php?qid=569/AJAX/Introduction